# App Inventor Compile Error Login Template Wordpress

Tags: android, wordpress, app-inventor

I worked my way through
http://eixerits.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/a-login-template/

I'm done with all the blocks, and I was quite sure it wont work for some reasons (e.g. tutorial is done when client_secret still was supported by Google; many blocks & variables = many opportunies for errors)

While tyring to compile I got the following error:

```
App Inventor is unable to compile this project. 
The compiler error output was 
________Preparing application icon
________Creating animation xml
________Determining permissions
________Generating manifest file
________Attaching native libraries
________Copying native libraries
________Attaching component assets
________Compiling source files
(compiling appinventor/ai_xxx/Login/Screen1.yail to appinventor.ai_SQ1P1T2ME.Login.Screen1)
ERROR: appinventor/ai_xxx/Login/Screen1.yail line 75: call to 'set-and-coerce-property!' has too few arguments (3; must be 4)
ERROR: appinventor/ai_xxx/Login/Screen1.yail line 75: call to 'set-and-coerce-property!' has too few arguments (3; must be 4)
Kawa compile time: 1.99 seconds
```

Is there any way to find out which block is meant?
Is there any way to read .yail files (or can it only be opened by blockeditor)?
Is there any other way to find the problem other than comparing all blocks 1 by 1?

Funny thing is that when I tried to compile some 7 hours ago it said

> ERROR: appinventor/ai_xxx/Login/Screen1.yail line 19: call to 'set-and-coerce-property!' has too few arguments (3; must be 4)

Comment: Problem solved

procedure "initColors" incomplete
set.Screen1.BackroundColor is empty

Beware: login_template.zip is incomplete in at least "initColors"
may have edited some other blocks as well

Answer (score 1):

To know which block is creating the error:

1. Export your app as `.aia` (Project/Export selected project (.aia) to
   my computer): the .aia should be created even if you get an error when building the .apk.
2. Then change the extension of your `.aia` to `.zip`
3. Go to the folder Your_app_name\src\appinventor\ai_your_username\Your_app_name
4. Open  the `.yail` file Go to the line indicated in the error ex for
   you line 75 (or 19)

The "words" in the first parenthesis will tell you which block it is.